# struts1 why session is not null after session.invalidate()

Tags: struts-1

Even though I invalidate the session meaning I called `session.invalidate()` in `signoutAction` class (struts action); why is the session obj still not null?

If I print the session object it display the class name of the session. If the session is not null, how do I prevent the end user clicking on back button to preview the previous page.

Sometimes I check based on whether the current user is null or not, if the user is null then I used `response.sendRedirect()` method to redirect to login page but the `response.sendRedirect()` method is not working properly.

Cam anybody help me?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. Please read our [FAQ].

Comment: You should post your code to get further help

Answer (score 1):

A method call on an object can't nullify the reference of this object in the caller. The session is not null after the call, but it's invalidated.

If you try to get an attribute from the session after it has been invalidated,you'll get an IllegalStateException.

If the user sends a new request to the server, it will get a new session, since the old one has been invalidated.

Comment: Thank you for giving reply.And can you please me suggestion how to make session object null

Comment: You can't. An object can't set to null. A reference to an object can be set to null. And the request will continue to have a reference to the invalidated session.

Answer (score 0):

Struts will create new session when it processes the action class.That's the framework code.
That's why you are not getting null when you called the invalidate method.